# Approximate volume of an ellipsoid using a random 'length' of the object

Tags: 3d, volume

I am a graduate student in an evolutionary biology program.  We're looking to estimate the effects of random mutations of egg size in the nematode C.elegans. The eggs can be approximated as a football (American).

The eggs are no more than 10 microns in length measured as the longest 'diagonal' (I'm not sure if diagonal is right in this context). We use a microfluidics device that measures hundreds of eggs per minute, but can only tell us the 'length' of the object as it passes through a laser.  The orientation of the egg as it passes through the laser cannot be controlled and can be reasonably assumed random. So essentially, I have too many estimates of the diameter of this object along a random axis, if that makes sense.  Is there a way to approximate the volume of this object?

Thank you
Ayush